# How to set the max value of a uniformly distributed random number with condition?

Tags: r, max, uniform-distribution

So I'm basically working with Monte Carlo and have a problem defining a random number with condition. The problem is only about defining the max value in `y` distribution with the condition `x=[a,b]`.

```
$f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$
 
$x=[a,b]; y = [0,\underset{x\in[a,b]}{\max}f(x)]$ 

      x = runif(n, min = a, max = b) 
    
    
      y = runif(n, min = 0, max = ???)
```

Could you please help how to define the max value of "y" in R?

Comment: From the formula, isn't it `y = runif(n, min = 0, max = max(f(x)))`?

Comment: I need to make upper limit of y distributin as the maximal value of exp(-x^2). It seems to be equal to 1 but I need to write it as a function because it depends on the interval of x.

Comment: You mean `y` as a function of  `x`?

Comment: Exactly. f(x) is the max value of y.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the desired output, but worthy an attempt

```
f <- function(x) exp(-x**2)
a <- 0.2
b <- 0.7
n <- 10
y <- runif(n, 0, max(f(runif(n, a, b))))
```